# Yii2: select last record from a hasMany relation

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

my knowledge on mysql is very basic and now im facing a "complex" (for me) query in which im stuck so thank you in advance if someone could give me some light on this.

I have three tables:

**Orders**

```
id | name | comments | ...
```

**OrderLines**

```
id | name | sDate | eDate | comments | ...
```

**OrderLinesStats**

```
id | lineID | date | status | ...
```

Every day OrderLinesStats is updated via a cron job and gets a new record with actual date, status and other fields so the highest id is the actual data.

Im trying to get that last stats row with a relation in yii2 as follows:

**in OrdersLines model:**

```
public function getLastOrdersLinesStats()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrdersLinesStats::className(), ['lineID' => 'id'])
        ->orderBy(['id'=>SORT_DESC])
        ->groupBy('lineID');
}
```

**OrdersModel:**

```
public function getOrdersLines()
    {
        return $this
            ->hasMany(OrdersLines::className(), ['orderID' => 'id'])
            ->orderBy(['typeID' => SORT_ASC, 'name' => SORT_ASC])
            ->with(['lastOrdersLinesStats']);
    }
```

But when I debug the query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `ordersLinesStats` WHERE `lineID` IN (1873, 1872, 1884, 1883, 1870, 1874, 1876, 1880, 1871, 1877, 1881, 1882, 1885, 1886, 1869, 1875, 1878) GROUP BY `lineID` ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

and doesnt give me the last stats record for each line... in fact, it gives me the oldest one. Seems that im missing something but i cant find it.

Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OrdersModel add getLastOrderLineStat() method that uses via() junction:

```
public function getLastOrderLineStat()
{
    return $this->hasOne(OrdersLinesStats::className(), ['lineID' => 'id'])
        ->orderBy(['id'=>SORT_DESC])
        ->groupBy('lineID')
        ->via('ordersLines');
}
```

If $model is an OrdersModel instance, you obtain the last stat row using:

```
$model->lastOrderLineStat
```

Comment: Thank you but this ends with the same query. Seems that i have to make a subquery because this one works straight to the db: SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `ordersLinesStats` WHERE `lineID` IN (1957, 1954, 2035, 1956, 1955, 1958) ORDER BY `ordersLinesStats`.`id` DESC) AS LastStatsTable GROUP BY `lineID`; any chance of doing this with activequery? Thanks again

Comment: I created a new question at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754901/yii2-subquery-within-model-relation) as original question has changed

Comment: To avoid a mass of sub database queries, you can use joinWith(['lastOrderLineStat']) in your AR query so it will be "preloaded" with the proper values.

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is change the `getLastOrdersLinesStats()` to be as follows:

```
public function getLastOrdersLinesStats()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrdersLinesStats::className(), ['lineID' => 'id'])
        ->orderBy(['id'=>SORT_DESC])
        ->one();
}
```

This basically returns the last OrderLinesStats row that you want for each Order

You can access this as follows:

if you have an object called `myOrder` for example 
then you can access the row you want as `myOrder->lastOrderLinesStats`

Comment: Thank you mrateb. This would work if I use that method on every single record and this ends with a big amount of queries to the db. I want to make a single query by using ->with(['lastOrdersLinesStats']); and seems that going with a subquery is the way to go.

Comment: I don't care if the answer doesn't resolve OP's issue. It solves mine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am just answering this to be thorough and hopefully help other's who stumble upon this page.

I recommend always including both, `hasOne` and `hasMany`. This way, you can pop the top record, or retrieve all of them.

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getUserPlan()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserPlan::className(), ['user_id' => 'id'])
        ->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])
        ->one();
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getUserPlans()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserPlan::className(), ['user_id' => 'id'])
        ->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])
        ->all();
}
```

`hasMany` will return an array of ActiveQuery Objects, where `hasOne` will return just an ActiveQuery Object by itself.

You use them like so (example in UserController on User model):

```
$model = $this->findOne($id);
```

or

```
$model = User::findOne($id);
```

or

```
$model = User::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();
```

---

Then grab the relations like so:

```
$plan = $model->userPlan
```

or

```
$plans = $model->userPlans
```

---

For userPlan:

```
$planId = $plan->id;
```

Handling userPlans:

```
foreach($plans as $plan) {
    $plan->id;
}
```

Comment: Your phpdoc is wrong. These methods do not return an ActiveQuery which is what you would expect from a relation, but these methods are no longer relations either.